# При клике по ссылке заполнить форму

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть:

- 3 ссылки
- форма с одним скрытым полем
- строка с текстом

Вопрос в том, как сделать, используя js, может быть и jquery, чтобы при клике по ссылке (понятно, что на событие клик по ссылке необходимо повесить js функцию, которая всё это сделает, вот ооооочень интересен код этой функции) в скрытое поле формы записывалось значение (скажем, для первой ссылки - 1, для второй -2, для третьей - 7), а строка с текстом менялась соответственно на Тест 1, Тест 2, Тест 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<a class="clickeable" param="1">Тест1</a>
<a class="clickeable" param="2">Тест2</a>
<a class="clickeable" param="7">Тест3</a>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden">
<div id="string"></div>

<script>
$('a.clickeable').click(function(e){
    $('#hidden').val(this.getAttribute('param'));
    $('#string').html(this.innerHTML);
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Хммм, логика понятна, но не работает :) не реагирует на клик :/
Бггг, всё работает, паника отменяется.

Comment: Заметил в своем коде такой баг, что не всегда работают конструкции вида this.getAttribute() в выражениях jquery. Почему? Не знаю. Заменял все на чисто-jquery вызовы аля $(this).attr() - и все работало :)  
Или может дело в том, что скрытый инпут не содержал явного объявления атрибутов? Попробуйте вместо приведенного инпута такой:  

    <input type="hidden" name="some_name" id="hidden" value="" />

Comment: Данный код на 100% отрабатывает, просто я его криво вставил :)